# Finding an Example for the following claim in Propositional Calculus?

Tags: logic, solution-verification, propositional-calculus, proof-theory

Let $\Sigma$ be in $WFF$, we say $\Sigma$ is **closed** if for every $a$ in $WFF$ if $\Sigma \vDash a$ then $a$ in $\Sigma$.

Claim:

> For every $\Sigma_1, \Sigma_2$ in $WFF$ such that $\Sigma_1$ is **closed**
> and $\Sigma_1$ is contained in $\Sigma_2$ then $\Sigma_2$ is **closed** too.

I think the above claim is wrong (especially after I failed to prove it for hours) but can't seem to find any contradiction example, any help?

If needed I have proved that if $\Sigma$ is **closed** then it's infinite.

---

**Note1:** By $\Sigma$ I mean big sigma (can't find right symbol).

**Note2:** By $\vDash$ I mean thee symbol without space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple example would be if $\Sigma_1$ is the closure of $\{p_1\}$ with respect to logical consequence , i.e. $\Sigma_1$ contains $p_1$ and all logical consequences of $p_1$. That is: $\Sigma_1 = \{ \phi \in WFF | \{ p_1\} \vDash \phi \} $.  While $\Sigma_2 = \Sigma_1 \cup \{ p_2 \}$

Then clearly $\Sigma_1$ is closed, and $\Sigma_1 \subseteq \Sigma_2$, but $\Sigma_2$ is not closed:  we have $\Sigma_2 \vDash p_2 \land p_2$, but $p_2 \land p_2 \not \in \Sigma_1$ (since $\Sigma_1 \not \vDash p_2 \land p_2$), and so also $p_2 \land p_2 \not \in \Sigma_2$

Comment: Sorry but this isn't clear at all, you have to define Σ1 clearly, plus it's not clear what you mean by {Q} there is no such symbol... we have p0, p1, p2 ... and (or,and,->)

Comment: @Algo Well, you never said in your post how your book/instructor defined WFF so I used symbols that most books use. Apparently not yours. Anyway, quick fix: instead of $P$ and $Q$ take $p_1$ and $p_2$. Post updated, also with an exact definition of $\Sigma_1$.

Comment: Thanks, one last note: I don't agree with "Then clearly Σ1 is closed" It may seem trivial but it's not at all. can you try doing it formally according to the definition?

Comment: @Algo Sure. Take any $a \in WFF$ and assume $\Sigma_1 \vDash a$. By definition of $\Sigma_1$, we know that any truth-assignment that sets $p_1$ to true will also set any statement in $\Sigma_1$ to True, and hence it will set all statements in $\Sigma_1$ to true. So, by the assumption that $\Sigma_1 \vDash a$, this means that any such truth-assignment will also set $a$ to true. Thus: $\{p_1\} \vDash a$, and thus $a \in \Sigma_1$.

Comment: Thanks, that helped a lot. In your definition of $\sum_1$ we can change {1} to 1 right?

Comment: @Algo Typically $\vDash$ is defined over a set, but sure, no one will mind if you just use $p_1$

Comment: Thanks, kindly take a look at: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4317469/for-every-sum-in-wff-sum-vdash-p-i-or-sum-not-vdash-p-i